# Is there a GUI in Ubuntu for folder based find and replace?

Tags: ubuntu, find-and-replace

Is there a GUI in Ubuntu for directory based mass find and replace? Preferrably one that works similar to Adobe Dreamweaver's find and replace system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no experience with Dreamweaver whatsoever it is not clear for me if you are looking for a tool to search/replace file names or strings within files in a directory hierarchy.

Anyway, software that is already in the repositories and you can install via synaptic and that should do what you ask is (edit: of course **all this software is FLOSS**, there are other freeware and commercial options too, if you wish so):

- If you are looking to mass-rename files, then [**Purrr**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/purrr/) does the trick. The website of the developer appears to have been squatted, so I linked the package description from ubuntu/karmic instead.
- If you are looking for replacing strings on an entire filetree, then a good program to use is [**Regexxer**](http://regexxer.sourceforge.net/) which exposes the power of regular expressions via a nice graphical interface. I just found out (but never tried myself) [**kfilereplace**](http://kfilereplace.sourceforge.net/), for KDE environments.